# Windows 8 Restarts Twice On Boot

Tags: windows-8, boot, reboot

I recently updated my computer from windows 8 to windows 8.1 and it has been working perfectly. Nothing has been wrong with it and then all of a sudden it began to restart on boot, two times in a row, and and then will boot regularly into Windows.

Some key facts about this computer:

1. It is on Windows 8.1
2. It is a laptop with two hard drive ; the boot drive is an SSD installed from a disc drive caddy
3. I have hibernation disabled from the command line.

Its really annoying to have to wait for it to restart twice before it boots and havent found anything . If anyone has any ideas to solve this problem it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you made sure all firmware, drivers, and BIOS/UEFI updates are current?

Comment: this is probably most properly referred to as a "double post cold boot." The reason varies and is almost always solved at the motherboard/BIOS level. You might get a little more info if you provide the laptop model and motherboard firmware version.

Comment: I have updated all of the drivers and flashed the most recent bios. 
My laptop is a HP DV6 Pavillion 7078ca with version F29 of the bios.

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=ob-124651-1&cc=ca&dlc=en&lc=en&os=4132&product=5286415&sw_lang=

Comment: @user1683391 Hello, This might be related to fast start up option in Windows 8.1. This is also referred to as Hybrid shut down. To disable this, Go to Control Panel->Power Option->Select "Choose what the power option do"->Click on "Change settings that are currently unavailable"-> Scroll down to "Shut down settings"->Uncheck "turn on fast startup". Please check this link.

http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html